# Missing packages suggestions won't work on Raspbian buster

Tags: apt, bash, raspbian-buster

I'm trying to get [`command-not-found`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/command-not-found) package to work. That's the one which tells what to install when the user types a missing command, for instance:

```
$ zbarcam
The program 'zbarcam' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install zbar-tools
```

However, when I try to set it up, I get the following error

```
$ sudo update-command-not-found 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/sbin/update-command-not-found", line 26, in <module>
col.create(db)
File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 94, in create
self._fill_commands(con)
File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 132, in _fill_commands
self._parse_single_contents_file(con, f, fp.stdout)
File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 271, in _parse_single_contents_file
priority = component_priorities[component]
KeyError: 'rpi'
```

I'm pretty certain I don't have anything non-standard in `apt` sources, and the issue seems to come from the `rpi` component which is indeed in the default `sources.list`:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Is there any way to get it to work, preferably without removing the `rpi` component?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install `command-not-found` on Raspbian Buster with:

```
pi@rasberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install command-not-found
```

It succeeds without error messages. After a reboot I get:

```
pi@rasberrypi:~ $ zbarcam 
Could not find the database of available applications, run update-command-not-found as root to fix this
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.7.3 final 0
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
Exception information:

local variable 'cnf' referenced before assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 23, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 93, in main
    if not cnf.advise(args[0], options.ignore_installed) and not options.no_failure_msg:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cnf' referenced before assignment

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo update-command-not-found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I get another result then you. `update-command-not-found` succeeds without errors but executing `zbarcam` gives always the same error as shown. So you should file a bug as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

***Update 2019sep09hkt2238***

(1) I ran "$ sudo apt-get install command-not-found" and got message saying OK, blah, blah, blah, version 18.04.5-1.

(2) "$ sudo update-command-not-found" returns nothing.  I guess it means no update to do.

(3) I don't understand the "rpi" component thing.  I read that there are 3 packages.

(4) I don't know what is "sources.list", and how to check if "rpi" is in that list.  Perhaps you can give me a bash statement to do that.  PS - I don't know how to use the weird "grep" thing. In other words, I am a linux newbie.

(5) Actually I don't even know what actually is the thing "repositories".  I guess it is a collection of warehouses storing millions of packages. :)

***Wrong Answer to delete later***

Yes, I could not install blah-utils in terminal mode, so I tried it in desktop and found it OK.  I can run blah now but don't know how to do the database thing. :)

[Blah running log tlfong01  2019sep09hkt1544](https://imgur.com/gallery/ncH1TZS)

Comment: Did `sudo update-command-not-found` run OK?

Comment: I didn't try that.  I only tried to install blah-utils but no luck, so I gave up and switched to desktop.  Just now I tried "$ sudo update-command-not-found" and found no error message.

Comment: I'm not sure it that was clear, but `blah-utils` is not a real package, I just made it up as an example. Of course, that doesn't explain the crashing in your log.

Comment: Oh my goodness. So I got it all wrong.  I wrongly thought that "blah" was a real command.  I know what is three blahs "blah blah blah" but not one "blah".  If you used "foo", perhaps I won't misunderstand.  Actually when I first met the word "foo" I thought it was a real thing.  I was never sure if it is "fool" in short.  It is only when I googled servers yesterday that I learned why Apache server is called Apache.  I am glad that I have a good English lesson today.

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed the question to hopefully avoid confusion. In any case, that [`rpi`](http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/buster/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages) component seems to break `command-not-found`, which otherwise works for me. Since it's only 3 packages, I suppose I can live without it for a while.

Comment: Just a follow-up, do you have that `rpi` thing in your `sources.list`?

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev, I am replying in my answer update.  Bed time.  See you tomorrow.